# Is a Schengen multiple-entry visa for eight days a "short-stay 90-day visa"?

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration

I have a Schengen 'C' visa for MULT entries. The duration of stay is eight days and the validity is from 15th July to 27th July.

Would it allow me the "90-day, short-stay visa"?

I am guessing not, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: If it says “8 days” then it's 8 days. 90 days is for people who don't need visas and for visas where the duration of stay is either “90 days” or “XXX”.

Comment: The rule "90 days in any 180 day period" only applies for non-EU citizens with visa waiver agreement (USA, Australia, Brazil etc) and schengen residence permit holders. I dont think it will apply for visa holders.

Comment: @pbu the rule also applies to visas with duration of 90 days or unspecified, as Relaxed says.

Comment: Since your visa is valid for 13 days, in your case you have an 8/13 rule.  Also, even if you enter the Schengen area less than a week before the 27th, you must leave on or before the 27th.  You cannot remain in the Schengen area after the visa's expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike, say, US visas, Schengen visas do not only need to be valid on the day of entry but also define how long you are allowed to stay in the area.

So if your visa sticker says “8 days” under “duration of stay” then it means you can only stay 8 days in the Schengen area under this visa. Similarly, you must leave the Schengen area before the end of your visa's period of validity, so before or on the 27th of July (unless you obtain another visa or status in the meantime obviously).

The whole “[90 days in any 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule)” business is only relevant for people who don't need a visa (in which case the maximum stay is always 90 days) and for visas that explicitly say “90 days” or possibly “XXX” under “duration of stay” (which should in principle be the case for all multiple-entry visas with more than 6 months validity and not necessarily all that relevant for shorter visas but that's another issue).